# How do I create a save function for an application that has multiple classes?

Tags: python, tkinter, architecture, software-design

I'm developing a program using Tkinter for my GUI. Right now I'm conceptualizing the entire project, so the code I will provide is very simplistic.

Essentially, I wanted to create a main window that has several widgets each written in their own classes. One of the widgets would be the navbar where "File" -> "Save As" would exist.

My issue with this is if I have navbar as a separate class that is instantiated in the master class, the save function written in the navbar would be unable to view the variables in the other classes.

I have thought of potentially two solutions for this, but I am not sure if either one is necessarily the right thing to do for best Software Engineering practices.

Potential solution 1: Create a separate thread that constantly waits for the user to click save. Once it clicks save it changes an event flag which causes the main class to call some save function to save all variables. My issue with this is it is a constant waste of resources. The thread will be wasting resources constantly waiting for the save button to be clicked.

Potential solution 2: Create the navbar in a separate class, but define the navbar functions in the main class that instantiates it. My issue with this is that it makes the main class colluded with extraneous functions that I would like to have defined elsewhere for better practices. Additionally, I am not entirely sure how I would do this but I am sure there is some way that it could be done if I spent time looking into it.

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self, rt):
        self.rt = rt
        self.navbar = navbar.NavBar(rt)
        self.rt.mainloop()

class NavBar(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.bg='red'
        self.text = tkinter.Text(self, height=1, width=30)
        self.text.insert(tkinter.END, "File")
        self.text.pack()
        self.grid(row=0, column=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title('Automation')
    main = Main(root)
```

Here, Navbar would have a button named File which if you scrolled over would generate a list of other buttons, one of which being "Save As". If this Save As button is clicked, I would want to be able to save all variables belonging to Main.

TLDR: I want to figure out the best way for me to create a save file functionality, being able to save variables from different classes that are all instantiated under a main umbrella class.

Comment: I think that if you create the `'save_as'` function inside `NavBar`, it will be able to access `main`.

Comment: You could pass `self` (from Main) into `NavBar`, or just provide the function arguments needed for the function. Or use an on-event function, like when this button is clicked - run this function, and just pass in the data needed.

Comment: @Skarlett hmm I didn't think about passing self as a parameter. Then I could create a private variable in NavBar such as self.main = main (main being the name of the parameter, self would be passed as the argument when declaring self.navbar = navbar.Navbar(self, rt))? And this would be able to access all of main's variables?

Comment: @Henry Yehp. Bad practice, but it will work. Event driven function would be seen as better practice. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm As seen in this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I will setup the `Main` class as the controller of all the `Frames`, and have the `Main` inherits from `Tk` directly. Below is a sample on how to access attributes from other classes using this approach:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.navbar = NavBar(self)
        self.another_frame = AnotherFrame(self)
        self.navbar.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.another_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

class NavBar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        tk.Button(self,text="Button of first frame",command=self.print_other_frame).pack()

    def print_other_frame(self):
        print (self.master.another_frame.entry.get()) #access master attributes

class AnotherFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry.insert(0,"Test from 2nd frame")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Main()
    root.title('Automation')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ahhh, thank you that makes sense. I like the way you structure Main. That is definitely a better approach. I'm not completely familiar with tkinter beyond a few mini applications. Is this considered good practice to pass self as a parameter like this?

Comment: Its very natural to use `self` as a parameter when you use OOP, so i would say its a normal practice.

Comment: Do you happen to know why the background functionality gets broken when I define it this way? If I modify code a little to add *args and **kwargs to NavBar and then when it gets created in Main define it so it has padx=40, bg='blue' the background doesn't actually change color for some reason.

Comment: after some testing I found out it is changing the border color of the frame, but not the background of the frame for some reason :o

Comment: Your frame only occupies the space it needs to. When you put a widget inside, normally it will "shrink" to the size of that widget so you can no longer see the background colour of the frame. You should be configuring the background colour of the widget instead.